# Why we use the progressImage property in the ProgressViewIOS component in react-native?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, reactjs, react-native

Why and how to use the `progressImage` property in the `<ProgressViewIOS/>` component in react-native ? The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/progressviewios#progressimage) doesn't seem to be understandable. Can anyone share a screenshot output of this property on the iOS? Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`progressImage` is an image to use for the portion of the progress bar that is filled in `ProgressViewIOS`.

If you provide a custom image for it, the `progressTintColor` property is ignored.

**Images:**

`progressImage.png` [image]

`trackImage.png` [image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, ProgressViewIOS, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("screen").width;

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ProgressViewIOS 
        style={{width: screenWidth - 30}}
        progress={0.5}
        progressViewStyle = 'default'
        trackImage={require('./trackImage.png')}
        progressImage={require('./progressImage.png')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it